# 504 Deadline Exceeded when I try to get information

Tags: python, firebase

I'm trying to get information in a Firebase database and export the information in a CSV but I receive frequently the "error 504 Deadline Exceeded", at the beginning I didn't receive this message but three month later I start to receive this error

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
import pandas as pd

#Initializing firebase
cred = credentials.Certificate("cred.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
########cuerpo
users = db.collection(u'module')
query_ref = users.where("identify.idHeroe", "==", "heroe001").limit(1000).stream()
print (query_ref)
column_name=['date','idvillian',"document"]
heroes = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_name)
heroes2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_name)
i=0
for user in query_ref:
    a=user.to_dict()
    heroes2 = pd.DataFrame([user.get("villian"),columns=['idvillian']])
    heroes2['date']=[user.get("date.date_date")]
    heroes2['document']=user.id
    heroes2['identidy']=a['name']
    heroes=pd.concat([heroes, heroes2])
    
print(heroes)
heroes.to_csv('ou33t.csv')
```

Comment: Check your API keys again and check your security rules. Firebase usually blocks out requests after some time if your security rules are not secure.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve my problem was create an index and limit my query to 20 documents.